# Issues Using geoplot.kdeplot with geopandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization, geopandas, geoplot

[image: Example of a kdeplot from the geopandas docs]

Im trying to make a kdeplot using geopandas.

this is my code:

**Downloading shape file**

```
URL = "https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/wkhw-cjsf?method=export&format=Shapefile"
response = requests.get(URL)
open('pd_data.zip', 'wb').write(response.content)

with zipfile.ZipFile('./pd_data.zip', 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall('./ShapeFiles')
```

**Making the geopandas data frame**

```
data = train.groupby(['PdDistrict']).count().iloc[:,0]
data = pd.DataFrame({ "district": data.index,
                    "incidences": data.values})

california_map = str(list(pathlib.Path('./ShapeFiles').glob('*.shp'))[0])

gdf = gdp.read_file(california_map)
gdf = pd.merge(gdf, data, on = 'district')
```

**Note:** I didn't include the link to the train set because it's not important for this question(use any data you want)

**This is the part that I don't get,
what arguments should I pass to the kdeplot function, like where I pass the shape file and where I pass the data?**

```
ax = gplt.kdeplot(
    data, clip=gdf.geometry,
    shade=True, cmap='Reds',
    projection=gplt.crs.AlbersEqualArea())
gplt.polyplot(boroughs, ax=ax, zorder=1)
```

Comment: struggling to get this working in my env as `kdeplot()` is crashing the kernel. `data` should be points https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html#kdeplot `collisions` is a geodataframe of points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- had a few challenges setting up an environment where I did not get kernel crashes.  Used none wheel versions of **shapely** and **pygeos**
- a few things covered in documentation [kdeplot](https://residentmario.github.io/geoplot/plot_references/plot_reference.html#kdeplot) *A basic kdeplot takes pointwise data as input*. You did not provide sample for `data` I'm not sure that it is point wise data.  Have simulated point wise data,  100 points within each of the districts in referenced geometry
- I have found I cannot use `clip` and `projection` parameters together.  One or the other not both
- shape file is passed to clip

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import geoplot as gplt
import geoplot.crs as gcrs

# setup starting point to match question
url = "https://data.sfgov.org/api/geospatial/wkhw-cjsf?method=export&format=Shapefile"
gdf = gpd.read_file(url)

# generate 100 points in each of the districts
r = np.random.RandomState(42)
N = 5000
data = pd.concat(
    [
        gpd.GeoSeries(
            gpd.points_from_xy(*[r.uniform(*g.bounds[s::2], N) for s in (0, 1)]),
            crs=gdf.crs,
        ).loc[lambda s: s.intersects(g.buffer(-0.003))]
        for _, g in gdf["geometry"].iteritems()
    ]
)
data = (
    gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=data)
    .sjoin(gdf)
    .groupby("district")
    .sample(100, random_state=42)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

ax = gplt.kdeplot(
    data,
    clip=gdf,
    fill=True,
    cmap="Reds",
    # projection=gplt.crs.AlbersEqualArea(),
)
gplt.polyplot(gdf, ax=ax, zorder=1)
```

[image]